# Creating a bash file from a script

Tags: bash, shell, automation, heredoc

Grettings, I'm a newbie trying to make a bash script that can automate the installation of several SBCs.

It creates several files, folders, cronjobs, tweeks some configurations.

I'm having difficulties creating other shell scripts.

I tried:

```
cat > cputemp.sh <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
while :
 do
        x=$( cat /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp )
        y=$( cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq )
        z=$(expr $y / 1000)
        t=$(expr $x / 1000)
        echo -en "\033[1K\r\e[91mTemperature:\e[0m" "\e[93m$tº\e[0m "
        echo -en "\e[91mFrequency:\e[0m" "\e[93m$z MHz\e[0m"
        sleep 2
done
EOF
```

but instead of putting those lines inside the file, it seems it's trying to run them. I get

```
cat: /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp: No such file or directory
cat: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq: No such file or directory
expr: syntax error: unexpected argument ‘1000’
expr: syntax error: unexpected argument ‘1000’
```

What am I missing? By the way, it can't find those locations because I'm testing the script on windows with WSL and not on the SBCs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you just need to escape the `$(...)` on variable assignments. Basically replace `$` with `\$`

Comment: If you are using Bash, you don't need `expr`; the arithmetic facilities are built into the shell. `z=$((y / 1000))` etc (though if you need fractions, try Awk or `bc`; but `expr` is integers only, too).

Answer (score 0):

Either create the heredoc surrounded by `'EOF'` or use `\$` when you create the vars

```sh
cat > cputemp.sh <<'EOF'
...
```